# Retrieve value from database sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have sqlite database handler that will create a table upon the user logging into the app. The server sends back some info about the user that is store. When the user goes to the next activity, I need to retrieve a value from this database and just store it locally. I'm not sure how to retrieve value 5 and store it in the activity OnCreate. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Database Handler:

```
    public HashMap<String, String> retrieveUser(){
    HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        user.put("first_name", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("last_name", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("dob", cursor.getString(4));
        user.put("userid", cursor.getString(5));
        user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(6));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    return user;
}
```

Edit: I solved it this way

```
dbh = new DatabaseHandler(this);
HashMap<String, String> details = dbh.retrieveUser();
    String UserId = details.get("userid");
```

Comment: First read simple concept of the sqlite database and here is ref link http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/sqlite-database-example/

Comment: What do you mean by `how retrieve value 5 and store it` ? Do you want to retrieve only 5 records ?

Comment: I meant just retrieve user.put("userid", cursor.getString(5));

Comment: That means you want to get only `userid` data ?

Comment: can't you just do `retrieveUser().get("userid");`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retreive on `userid` column from your table then try as below by quering only for the `userid`.

```
public HashMap<String, String> retrieveUser(){
    HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  userid FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        user.put("userid", cursor.getString(0));
       cursor.moveToNext();
       user.add("userVal",cursor.getString(0)); 
      }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return user;
}
```